# How to share service between angular app and angular element

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular9, angular-elements

I have an angular app upgraded to angular 9 and I am using angular element in it which is also upgraded to angular 9. I have a service module (angular 9) which I am importing in my angular app. My angular element also imports the same service. I want to have the single instance of that service shared between my angular app and the angular element. Angular 9 has new service injection options available now called 'platform'. As per angular doc https://next.angular.io/api/core/Injectable

'platform' : A special singleton platform injector shared by all applications on the page.

I changed my service to inject from root to platform level. But I am still seeing two instances of my service one in my app and other in angular element.

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'platform'
})

How can I have single instance of my service shared between my app and angular element.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this one?

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

I might be late to the party, but I believe the problem might be that you are including Angular twice?

Since Angular has changed so much since the original post, I doubt you're still using Angular 9. If using an older version of Angular, you will need to look into your vendor.js bundle. It should have the same content for both apps, and be included only once in the index.html. Customizing it could be achieved by tinkering with a custom webpack config.

Otherwise in 2024, with latest Angular, I would recommend [Native federation](https://www.angulararchitects.io/en/blog/micro-frontends-with-modern-angular-part-1-standalone-and-esbuild/). If you're a few major versions delayed, then [Module federation](https://www.angulararchitects.io/en/blog/the-microfrontend-revolution-module-federation-in-webpack-5/) might be for you instead. In either case you have to look into the dependency management, and make sure that you A) use the exact same Angular version down to the patch version OR B) tell Module federation to map different versions to the same Angular (the article series on module federation lays out your options in detail).